# Why does + operator between string and int acts as substr

Tags: c++, string

When trying to concatenate a `string` with an `int` (without using the `std::to_string`, just to see what happens), I saw that there was no compilation error but the actual result is quite strange.

I tried to search on cplusplus.com how the `+` operator is defined for `string`, but I couldn't find any definition of this operator between `string` and `int`.

The code used to test the concatenation is the following :

```
std::cout << "Test" + 3 << std::endl;
```

I was expecting a compilation error, but I simply got a `t` in the console, which surprised me a bit.

Why does this operator acts this way, and where is it defined?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You have + operator btw `const char *` and `int`

Comment: There's no `string` in your example. `"Test"` is a `const char [5]`, not a `string`. The rest is just "pointer arithmetic". Inherited directly from C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not using `string`+ `int`, you are doing `const char*` + `int`, that's pointer arithmetics.

That's a pointer to `"Test"`, you increment it by 3, which means the pointer points to the substring `"t"`.

Answer (score 3):

As already answered you have pointer arithmetic due to using [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

To see what happens when you use `std::string` you need to either cast explicitly:

```
std::cout << std::string("Test") + 3 << std::endl;
```

or if you have C++14 or later to use [operator ""s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s)

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
std::cout << "Test"s + 3 << std::endl;
```

Comment: Or simply ` "Test" << 3 `?

Comment: @JVApen not quite - "solution" I provided would not compile (as expected by OP), your is a fix which is different case.

Comment: @Slava `std::string + int` [doesn't work](https://www.ideone.com/XEeCZh). You simply cannot append an `int` to a `string` as there is no `operator+` for that purpose.

Comment: @RemyLebeau did I say otherwise? I even said that in my comment above. OP was expecting compilation error and was surprised that it compiles. I explained how to get compilation error OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

`operator+` has a [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `operator<<`, so this statement:

```
std::cout << "Test" + 3 << std::endl;
```

Get treated by the compiler as if you had written this instead:

```
std::cout << ("Test" + 3) << std::endl;
```

`"Test"` is a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) of type `const char[5]`, which will *decay* into a pointer to the `T` character. So, adding `+3` to `"Test"` performs [pointer arithmetic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Pointer_arithmetic), thus a `const char*` pointer that is pointing at the `t` character gets passed to `operator<<`, as if you had written code like this instead:

```
const char *ptr = "Test";
ptr = ptr + 3;
std::cout << ptr << std::endl;
```

Changing `"Test"` to a `std::string` won't work by default, either:

```
std::cout << std::string("Test") + 3 << std::endl;
```

Because there is no standard `operator+` that allows an `int` to be added to a `std::string` (you would have to define your custom operator if you want that).

So, to fix this, you have two choices:

1. Convert the `int` to a `std::string`:

   ```
   std::cout << "Test" + std::to_string(3) << std::endl;
   ```
2. use `operator<<` instead of `operator+`:

   ```
   std::cout << "Test" << 3 << std::endl;
   ```